# Python doesn't read PYTHONSTARTUP

Tags: python, windows-7

On Windows 7, CMD:

```
  C:\Users\me> set PYTHONSTARTUP="C:\Python27\startup.py"
```

On Python 2.7-64:

```
  >>> os.environ.get('PYTHONSTARTUP')
  >>>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be
   c:\Users\me> set PYTHONSTARTUP="C:\Python27\startup.py"

Comment: solved!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
need to go to: Control Panel\System and Security\System --> advanced --> environment varibles and add the PYTHONSTARTUP there.

Comment: Are you running everything on the same shell? Yeah your set on the cmd shell is only valid for that cmd session.

Answer (score 0):

need to go to: `Control Panel` \ `System and Security` \ `System` --> `advanced` --> `environment varibles` and add the PYTHONSTARTUP there

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it was not set in your shell, in the first place.

In Windows Powershell there are 3 different ways: *Temporary* (for the session), *Locally* (to the user) and *Globally* (system wide).

```
$env:PYTHONSTARTUP="C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.pyrc"                                                  # Set it Temporarily (for this session)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONSTARTUP", 'C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.pyrc', 'User')     # Set it Locally:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONSTARTUP", 'C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.pyrc', 'Machine')  # Set it Globally: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
setx /m PYTHONSTARTUP "%HOME%\.pyrc"                                                            # Set it Globally: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (also in CMD)
```

You can then also check from your terminal (without starting the Python REPL) to see if it's present, using this one-liner:

```sh
python -c "import os;L=[f'{k}={v}' for k,v in os.environ.items()]; print('\n'.join(L))"
```